# OnCreate error - Gallery test(4.0.1)

Tags: android, android-activity, gallery, oncreate

this is my first question, but this forum helped me a lot in the last 2 months!!!

I tried to make an "Gallery" on my Android app, i solved it for 1 Gallery, but after i tried to make more "Galleries", i got an error in my "OnCreate".
This is my onCreate:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //try { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_combination);

            Gallery h = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery_head);
            h.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter_head(this));

            h.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Create_combination.this, "" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

i make this for 3 times (for 3 Galleries)

My class "ImageAdapter:head":

```
    public class ImageAdapter_head extends BaseAdapter {
int mGalleryItemBackground;
private Context hContext;

private Integer[] mImageIds_head = { R.drawable.layout, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
R.drawable.test2, R.drawable.layout, R.drawable.layout,
R.drawable.layout, R.drawable.layout };


public ImageAdapter_head(Create_combination create_combination) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void ImageAdapter(Context h) {
hContext = h;

TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground , 0);


a.recycle();
}

public int getCount() {
return mImageIds_head.length;
//return mImageIds_upper.length;
//return mImageIds_lower.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}


ImageView h = new ImageView(hContext);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
h.setImageResource(mImageIds_head[position]);
h.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
h.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
h.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

return (h);

}

}
```

And here are my Errors:

```
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1956    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1981 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 123    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1147  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4424    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
    Daemon Thread [<8> FinalizerWatchdogDaemon] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<7> FinalizerDaemon] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<6> ReferenceQueueDaemon] (Running)  
    Thread [<11> AsyncTask #1] (Running)
```

logcat:

```
11-18 18:24:07.371: I/ActivityManager(159): START {cmp=in.dressin/com.example.hellogallery.Create_combination} from pid 1890
11-18 18:24:07.511: D/dalvikvm(159): GC_CONCURRENT freed 552K, 20% free 9123K/11335K, paused 3ms+7ms
11-18 18:24:07.901: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:07.901: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:07.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:07.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:08.401: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:08.401: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:08.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:08.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:08.901: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:08.901: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:08.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:08.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:09.401: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:09.401: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:09.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:09.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:09.911: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:09.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:09.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:09.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:10.411: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:10.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:10.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:10.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:10.901: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:10.901: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:10.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:10.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:11.401: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:11.401: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:11.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:11.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:11.901: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:11.901: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:11.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:11.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:12.431: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:12.431: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:12.441: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:12.441: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:12.911: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:12.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:12.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:12.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:13.401: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:13.401: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:13.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:13.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:13.901: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:13.901: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:13.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:13.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:14.401: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:14.401: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:14.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:14.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:14.901: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:14.901: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:14.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:14.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:15.401: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:15.401: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:15.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:15.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:15.911: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:15.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:15.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:15.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:16.411: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:16.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:16.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:16.411: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:16.901: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:16.901: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:16.911: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:16.911: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:17.401: I/Process(159): Sending signal. PID: 1890 SIG: 3
11-18 18:24:17.401: I/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 18:24:17.401: W/ActivityManager(159): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-18 18:24:17.411: D/dalvikvm(1890): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
11-18 18:24:17.421: I/dalvikvm(1890): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 18:24:17.421: W/ActivityManager(159): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{411fec30 in.dressin/com.example.hellogallery.Create_combination}
11-18 18:24:20.261: I/WindowManager(159): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
11-18 18:24:22.971: I/WindowManager(159): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
11-18 18:24:28.741: I/InputDispatcher(159): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{412958e0 token=Token{413a5178 ActivityRecord{411fec30 in.dressin/com.example.hellogallery.Create_combination}}}.  5001.1ms since event, 5000.8ms since wait started
11-18 18:24:28.741: I/WindowManager(159): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{412958e0 token=Token{413a5178 ActivityRecord{411fec30 in.dressin/com.example.hellogallery.Create_combination}}}
11-18 18:24:33.741: I/InputDispatcher(159): Dropped event because it is stale.
```

Please help me :)

greetings, felix!

Comment: Are you sure that's all of the stack trace? Often in Android stack traces there are 2-3 sections of stack trace, all of them quite useful.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include that?

Comment: You've posted the wrong part of logcat.  If you are to be successful writing Android apps, then learning how to read logcat is an important step,  Look for the stack trace from your exception.  http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/11/android-tutorial-7-how-to-debug-the-android-mobile-application-with-logcat/